# Laravel4-nginx-fpm file not found on rewrite

Tags: php, nginx, laravel, laravel-4, fastcgi

Hello I am using laravel 4 on Nginx with FastCGI, I am pretty new to Nginx and FastCGI.

The situation is when I use the urls as $doc_root/index.php?my_uri it works but when I try pretty URLs it does not work.

this is my nginx configuration

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name localhost;
rewrite_log  on;

index index.php;    
root   /home/mostafa/public_html;

#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}


if (!-d $request_filename) {
     rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
}
#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

#pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/mostafa/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
}

location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|jpe?g|JPG|png|svg|woff)$ {
        expires 365d;

}
 }
```

and this is my FastCGI file

```
;prefix = /path/to/pools/$pool

; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
user = www-data
group = www-data

; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses on a
;                            specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

The case is when I try a url like this 
`http://localhost/laravel-master/public/index.php?current` it works and when I try it with out the index.php it does not work, and gives a file not found and in error log it says

FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading

although according to this tutorial it should work

http://daylerees.com/nginx-configuration-for-daylerees-dot-com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after searching for a few while and so many try outs, I found that the error was in my nginx config document root, it must be set to `laravel-master/public/`

The error I was getting was because the rewritten URLs were forwarded to `$document_root/index.php` which is `localhost/index.php` which of course does not exist, so changing the document root to my laravel master did the trick and the URLs where rewritten to `localhost/laravel-master/public/index.php`